# Проблема с сигналами

Tags: android, qt

В моей программе используется `QTableWidget`, подключенный к слоту сигналом `itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem*)`. Проблема в том, что после изменения мы смотрим, не привысило ли число из таблицы максимально возможное значение. Если превысило, то записываем максимально возможное значение. Так вот. Проблема в том, что после записи срабатывает сигнал и мы выполняем этот слот дважды. Решение было найдено - `QSignalBlocker`, но это не работает на `Android`. Вопрос: как переделать, чтобы работало и на `Android`?

Comment: blockSignal(true) вообще не работает в данном случае

Comment: Почему бы не делать проверку до обновления значения в таблице?

Comment: @PavelParshin в смысле? Вы не поняли? Поясняю еще раз: человек меняет значение, срабатывает сигнал и мы смотрим, не превысило ли оно максимальное. Если превысило, то вписываем максимально возможное. И проблема в том, что когда программа вписывает, то сигнал срабатывает, чего нам не надо.

Comment: я понял все прекрасно. Вот и задаю вопрос, почему бы не делать проверку ДО записи значения в модель.

Comment: @PavelParshin не можете дать пример, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Взять виджет ввода `QLineEdit`, прикрутить к нему валидатор `QIntValidator` (ну, или какой там нужен валидатор), и установить виджет в ячейку таблицы.
Тогда в принципе невозможно будет ввести более максимального числа.

Comment: попробую, спасибо